# Google Places API: Searching for names containing spaces

Tags: google-places-api

Is it possible to search for names containing spaces?

```
name: ['Burger&nbsp;King|Subway']  //fails
name: ['McDonald|Subway|Chipotle'] // works
```

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.4,-112.0&radius=5000&name=McDonald|Subway|Chipotle&sensor=false&key=yourkeyhere

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. name=Subway|McDonald|Burger%20King does return Burger King correctly but excludes the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing a Places Search Request with multiple keywords or names is not officially supported  by the Places API therefore is not guaranteed to return accurate results.

If you believe support for multiple keywords or names would be a useful feature, please file a 'Places API - Feature Request' [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: Filed at: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4845
Please star this issue if it's important to you.

Comment: It won't let me submit the issue! :(

I starred the issue @saxman linked.

Answer (score 7):

As SKAR said, add %22 when you have spaces. Your search term, instead of Burger King, becomes "Burger King".

URL, as suggested by SKAR:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=-41.21545,174.89416&radius=10000&name=%22strike%20entertainment%20centre%22&sensor=true&key=[YourKey]

Do not **replace** your %20 (Spaces) by %22, but **add** them before and after your search term.

Cheers

Comment: This should be the answer-- names containing spaces require quotes(%22 is an escaped quote character).

Answer (score 2):

Use "+" if there is space inbetween the name -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=33.4,-112.0&radius=5000&name=Burger+King&sensor=false&key=YourKey
```

Answer (score 2):

Add **%22** (quotes) when you have spaces

e.g.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/xml?location=-41.21545,174.89416&radius=10000&name=strike%22entertainment%22centre&sensor=true&key=[YourKey]

Thanks,
SKAR

Comment: You put quotes (%22) instead of spaces (%20)? It seems to work so far... Why?

Comment: It seems the KEYWORD query is bugged even when wrapped with %22 and the NAME works. 
Please see this [link](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4845)

Comment: @SKAR im using GET method and building query as you have shown above but i don't know how can add %20 manually if there is space in search string??

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: Sry I could not get your query but as far I understand it, replace white characters with %20.

Comment: @SKAR how to replace white characters with %20?

Comment: use text.replace(" ","%22");