# Multiple names in Google Places

Tags: google-places-api

Basically, my problem is the same as here: [Google Places API: Searching for names containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903363/google-places-api-searching-for-names-containing-spaces)

If you use %20, it works for the one name containing it, but ignores the rest.

I have a need to find restaurants near by, but only restaurants I've got additional information on, so I've got a list of 10 restaurants, I want to show the closest restaurants of the 10, it appears as though google places may not support this (spaces in names of restaurants), is there another API I should be looking at?

Comment: Please post an example HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing these restaurants in your own database?

If you are, you need to do proximity search. MySql & Postgres has GIS plugins that support this given a lat/long.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've got a list of restaurants I have certain information on (prices, reviews, not location though), let's say for example:

Mcdonalds
Burger King
Starbucks

I want to use the google places API to show the nearest Mcdonalds, Burger King and Starbucks, so I can then show the prices for those restaurants.

My problem is, searching for Mcdonalds|Starbucks works perfectly, but if you add in Burger%20King|Mcdonalds|Starbucks it only returns hits on Burger King, it ignores anything else that your searching for as soon as you use the %20.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a Places Search Request with multiple keywords or names is not officially supported by the Places API therefore is not guaranteed to return accurate results.

[Google Places API: Searching for names containing spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903363/google-places-api-searching-for-names-containing-spaces)

Comment: I linked to that same post in my original question... I know it's not officially supported, but hoping someone may have found a way around it.