# VuetifyJS Advanced slots autocomplete with Google Places API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-places-api, vuetify.js, google-places

I need to get [VuetifyJS advanced slots](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes#advanced-slots) to work with the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/intro). Currently some addresses only show up in the *autocomplete dropdown* after clicking the **"x"** in the form field to delete the input text.

Here is a CodePen demonstrating the issue:
https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/Bvwzza
**EDIT: I just found out that populating the dropdown menu with the suggestions is the issue. The suggestions are visible in the console.log but not in the dropdown. Any ideas how to fix this issue?**

(Some addresses work right away, some not at all - it's pretty random. 
Any ideas on how to fix this are very welcome.)

JS:

```
    new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    isLoading: false,
    items: [],
    model: null,
    search: null,
  }),

  watch: {
    search(val) {
      if (!val) {
          return;
      }

      this.isLoading = true;

      const service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
      service.getQueryPredictions({ input: val }, (predictions, status) => {
        if (status != google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          return;
        }

        this.items = predictions.map(prediction => {
          return {
            id: prediction.id,
            name: prediction.description,
          };
        });

        this.isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-toolbar color="orange accent-1" prominent tabs>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title class="title mr-4">Place</v-toolbar-title>
      <v-autocomplete
        v-model="model"
        :items="items"
        :loading="isLoading"
        :search-input.sync="search"
        chips
        clearable
        hide-details
        hide-selected
        item-text="name"
        item-value="symbol"
        label="Search for a place..."
        solo
      >
        <template slot="no-data">
          <v-list-tile>
            <v-list-tile-title>
              Search for a <strong>Place</strong>
            </v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </template>
        <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ item, selected }">
          <v-chip :selected="selected" color="blue-grey" class="white--text">
            <v-icon left>mdi-map-marker</v-icon>
            <span v-text="item.name"></span>
          </v-chip>
        </template>
        <template slot="item" slot-scope="{ item, tile }">
          <v-list-tile-avatar
            color="indigo"
            class="headline font-weight-light white--text"
          >
            {{ item.name.charAt(0) }}
          </v-list-tile-avatar>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title v-text="item.name"></v-list-tile-title>
            <v-list-tile-sub-title v-text="item.symbol"></v-list-tile-sub-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
          <v-list-tile-action> <v-icon>mdi-map-marker</v-icon> </v-list-tile-action>
        </template>
      </v-autocomplete>
      <v-tabs
        slot="extension"
        :hide-slider="!model"
        color="transparent"
        slider-color="blue-grey"
      >
        <v-tab :disabled="!model">Places</v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
    </v-toolbar>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

(I enabled the relevant API's in Google Cloud.)

Comment: Looks like an exceeded quota issue (see your browser console). If I use my own API key, the demo works ok. The main issue seems to be your requests are not throttled, so *every* keypress that changes `search` sends an API request, causing your quota to be quickly depleted.

Answer (score 4):

the problem is the number of request you do in a certain amount of time. Every character triggers an request to the GoogleApi which is resulting in.

[image: Screenshot]

I think the error_message isn't totally correct while I trying afterwards it gives me a result.

To solve this,

1. upgrade your GoogleApi account
2. Debounce your input. so wait till the customer is not typing for half a second and then sen a request to The googleApi. You could use lodash to implement to debounce functionality https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce

Comment: Even if you do just 1 request by pasting a complete date into the input field the issue remains. In that case the drop down doesn't show as well. It needs to be a different/another issue, what do you think?

Comment: What happens if you monitor the network data, What kind of response do you get from google? Same as above?

Comment: I think I found the issue. It looks like Google API needs the exact String to show it in the dropdown autocomplete. If you look up "big great street" with **spaces in between** nothing shows up - but if you look up "big**-**great**-**street" it works. Is there an API option to let the version without spaces show up as well?

Comment: Does quoting help like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903363/google-places-api-searching-for-names-containing-spaces

It's the places api but probably it works the same

Comment: I just found out that populating the dropdown menu with the suggestions is the issue. The suggestions are visible in the console.log but not in the dropdown. Any ideas how to fix this issue?

Comment: Since JS processes everything in async, you probably have to wait on the result. try async/await: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: Where do I have to add the **await** in this case?

Comment: JS does *not* process everything in async. And the problem is unrelated to `async`/`await`, since the handler is specified in a callback already.